# Error message when running a test suite (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I installed  ChromeDriver 2.30 and sometimes I get an error message when I run a test on a Chrome browser.

```
test_suite.py [7688:11092:0626/144911.859:ERROR:service_manager.cc(158)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser
...
[8128:10612:0626/144939.880:ERROR:service_manager.cc(158)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_plugin from binding interface: memory_instrumentation::mojom::Coordinator exposed by: content_browser
[8128:10612:0626/144948.463:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(1054)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
```

What does the error message mean, and how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, selenium webdriver using chrome driver in python 27, never seen that error before.

Comment: Use PyCharm IDE instead of VSCode, it works perfectly for me